# C++ - Checking if string is empty

Tags: c++, string

I have really hard time to get this. If my **input** is **empty**, I mean *"Enter button"* (means **empty string, whitespaces**), how can I detect it using **C++**?.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string a;
    cin>>a;

    if(a.empty())
        cout<<"I";
    else
        cout<<"V";

    return 0;    
}
```

How can I print "I" if it is an empty string and how does it work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the input succeeds with the code as is, `a` won't be empty. However, input may fail. You should always verify inputs were successful, though.

Comment: `a.empty()` returns `true` if `a` is _'really'_ empty (e.g. `""` and nothing more, no whitespace or anything).

Comment: I somewhat suspect an XY problem. Checking to see if `a` is "empty" is not the proper way to see if it was read at all. you should be validating the *stream* state; not the string state. `if (std::cin >> a)...` Or perhaps you're trying to pull a *line* from `std::cin` and determine if it is empty after ripping whitespace? It is a little more complicated in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an empty input to be accepted you have to tell the input stream to not skip whitespace using the [`noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) IO manipulator:

```
cin >> noskipws >> a;
```

Your code should then work as you want it to.

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood you correctly:

1. If you want to **check** if provided string is **empty**, just use `isspace()` function. It checks whether the string is null, empty or white space.
2. If you want to accept empty input, just use `getline()` function.

   ```
   std::string inputValue;
   std::getline (std::cin,name);
   cout << name;
   ```

   Function `getline()` accepts **empty** input by default.

Comment: Thank u,i have to use getline() func.
@mateudu

Answer (score 2):

The formatted input functions, i.e., the `operator>>()` conventionally start off skipping whitespace. The input operator for `std::string` certainly does that. This is probably not what you want.

You can disable this behavior using the manipulator `std::noskipws`, e.g., using

```
if (std::cin >> std::noskipws >> a) {
     std::cout << (a.empty()? "a is empty": "a is non-empty") << '\n';
}
```

However, the whitespace will be left in the stream. You'll probably want to `ignore()` it. From the sounds of it, you really want to read a line of input and do something special if it only contains spaces:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, a)) {
    std::cout << (std::any_of(a.begin(), a.end(),
                              [](unsigned char c){ return !std::isspace(c); })
                  ? "a contains non-space characters"
                  : "a contains only spaces") << '\n';
}
```